Minimum working example for Slickgrid + Webpack + Flask
I want to include slickgrid (npm install slickgrid, slickgrid.net) in my Python Flask project and I don't want to use CDN, so I'm looking at a Webpack solution.
I have been following the procedure for integrating npm packages in Flask using Webpack and as a starting point I have forked the following minimum working example https://github.com/jrybicki-jsc/flasknpm which by default works fine.
I change the file my.js to simply:
import SlickGrid from 'slickgrid';

but when I run the command npm run build (which uses webpack), I get the following error:
ERROR in ./node_modules/slickgrid/dist/esm/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (67:54)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|    */
|   stopPropagation() {
|     this._isPropagationStopped = !0, this.nativeEvent?.stopPropagation();
|   }
|   /**
 @ ./src/my.js 1:0-34

As a MWE I would like to get Slickgrid "Example1" working, which can be found at this link in the official slickgrid repo:
example1
Anybody has some pointers on how to integrate Slickgrid with Flask through Webpack?

It was not a WebPack issue. Apparently Babel is required for the proper translation. I followed this answer to find my way to a solution, in particular the answer from the Babel team member khizerrehandev. I choose this because it was using the most recent version of Babel7 and works with the latest Webpack5.
After some trial and error I came to this MWE.
EDIT: I noticed that the original solution (still reported here below under "VERSION-0" for completeness was having issues displaying the position of the Slickgrid grid. Sometimes it would show with a "top: 32pix" (correct) and sometimes with "top: 108px" randomly as I would refresh the browser page. I later found out that this is because the slick-alpine-theme.css file was loaded directly into the index.html and not bundled into the bundle.js. In "VERSION-1" I show the changes to bundle the css with webpack and avoid this issue.

VERSION-0
package.json
{
  "name": "slickgrid_webpack_flask_MWE",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.93.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "slickgrid": "^5.11.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.15.2"
  }
}

.babelrc
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}

webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './static/my.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')
  },
  module: {
      rules: [{
              test: /\.(js)$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader'
              }
          }
      ]
  },
};

app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

index.html
Notice that here I hard copied slick-alpine-theme.css from the node_modules directory to my static folder. In fact I don't know how to load the css directly from node_modules or somehow include it in the bundle. Also notice the type="module" when loading the bundle.
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='slick-alpine-theme.css') }}" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bundle.js') }}"></script>
    <title>slickgrid webpack flask MWE</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myGrid" class="slick-container" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>

my.js
This is the same code as example1-simple.html with slight modifications
import { SlickGrid } from 'slickgrid';
import Sortable from 'sortablejs';

var grid;
var columns = [
{id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title"},
{id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"},
{id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete", width: 90 },
{id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start"},
{id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish"},
{id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven", width: 90 }
];

var options = {
enableCellNavigation: true,
enableColumnReorder: false
};

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    data[i] = {
      title: "Task " + i,
      duration: "5 days",
      percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      start: "01/01/2009",
      finish: "01/05/2009",
      effortDriven: (i % 5 == 0)
    };
}


grid = new SlickGrid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

Now for the bundle.js creation with the command
npm run build and of course launch flask.
One thing that is left to find out for me is if I included sortablejs correctly.

VERSION-1
To solve the issue mentioned at the beginning we need to bundle the css file with bundle.js using webpack. This requires three changes:
index.html
Remove the line
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='slick-alpine-theme.css') }}" type="text/css"/>

my.js
Add the line
import "./slick-alpine-theme.css"

webpack.config.js
Add the rule
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader']
}

The last steps are to install the npm packages
npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader

and rebuild `npm run build'

You are getting an error from the SlickGrid ESM dist folder, this proves that you should use the ESM approach with named imports. However you're trying to import it using default export which I don't think the ESM bundle as default export and so that is not the correct approach for ESM import.
If you take a look at 1 of the ESM Example you can see the code with import like this
import {
  Editors,
  Formatters,
  SlickGlobalEditorLock,
  SlickRowSelectionModel,
  SlickColumnPicker,
  SlickDataView,
  SlickGridMenu,
  SlickGridPager,
  SlickGrid,
  Utils,
} from '../dist/esm/index.js';
// OR preferably use the code below when installing from npm
// import { SlickGrid, ... } from 'slickgrid';

just replace from '../dist/esm/index.js' (because that is only meant to be used by the demo itself) with from 'slickgrid'. So you should have something like below and that should get you started
import { SlickGrid, SlickDataView } from 'slickgrid';

I have never used Python so I'm not entirely sure but I hope it works for you

Thanks for the reply but I'm not clear what I am doing wrong. In my my.js I do include the same line that you suggest import SlickGrid from 'slickgrid';. I get the error when I use webpack. Does this mean that webpack is not configured properly or that Slickgrid does not work with webpack?

No you're not using the same thing, you are missing the curly braces in the imports, it's import { SlickGrid } from 'slickgrid'; which is defined as a "named" import. Without the curly braces it's what we call a default import, there's a big difference between a named import vs a default import.
